# MS ACCESS Query dates range from linked Excel return wrong end date

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am working on MS ACCESS query to find data between two dates from linked Excel and input dates from Access form textboxes. Returned "Start date" has no problem, but "End date" missed one day. I tried to use different date format but failed and search a long time but no idea. Could any advice? Many thanks

[image: The data:]

[image: The input text boxes]

[image: The result is not contain 12/28/2020]

The codes:

```
WHERE TransactionDetail.transactionDate >= Forms![Reports]![Text0] AND TransactionDetail.transactionDate <= Forms![Reports]![Text1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because the data has both date and time parts, so the combined datetime is greater than the date part alone. Try using `DateValue()`:

```
WHERE DateValue(TransactionDetail.transactionDate) >= Forms![Reports]![Text0] AND DateValue(TransactionDetail.transactionDate) <= Forms![Reports]![Text1]
```

Comment: you are great. According to your method, the problem has been solved! Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad that solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish/need to take advantage of an index on *transactionDate*, you can use:

```
WHERE TransactionDetail.transactionDate >= Forms![Reports]![Text0] AND TransactionDetail.transactionDate < DateAdd("d", 1, Forms![Reports]![Text1])
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. Finally the problem is solved, thanks!

Comment: Great! Then please mark your question as answered.